# How to sync Active Directory Pictures with CRM Users

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to Sync the pictures from active directory into CRM Users?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an OOB functionality to sync the Active Directory pictures to CRM Users.

You need to develop your own synchronization.